# Using Regex to sort through a list of files

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm writing a script to sort through a list of files, get the newest file which matches a particular file name, and copy it to another folder.
I'm writing this in PHP, then setting it up to run at a certain time each day using a CRON.

The files are named likes this:
VS-order-export-105.xml
VS-order-export-104.xml
current-VS-order-export-105,xml
current-VS-order-export.104.xml

I need to get the latest of these files, with the pattern 'order-export-(number).xml'. Those prefixed 'current-' should be ignored.

I can't seem to get the Regex right to do this. Here's what I've got:

```
<?php $src = '/public_html/folder/exports/';
$files_src = scandir($src, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
foreach($files_src as $file) {
    if (preg_match('/(^VS-), (.*)/A', $file) && !is_dir($src . $file)) {
        $newest_file_src = $files_src[1];
        $newest_file_path_src = $src . $files_src[1];
        $dest_file_path = '/public_html/orders/';
        rename($newest_file_path_src, $dest_file_path);
    }
} ?>
```

Please can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just looking to get the latest "VS-order-export-###" file or are there some other "VS-something-something" files you need to do the same thing for?

Comment: Just the latest VS-order-export-### file

Comment: There is no comma and a space in the file names that you are trying to match. For a more specific match, try `^VS-order-export-\d+\.xml$` https://regex101.com/r/atBs9C/1

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird. That almost works, aside from I'm getting an error with the 'gm' options as follows: PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g'
Any thoughts on how to get around this please?

Comment: Try `\AVS-order-export-\d+\.xml\z` https://regex101.com/r/hjeG1C/1

Comment: I think that PHP preg_replace doesn't offer those modifiers?

Comment: You use `preg_match` looking at the code, right? `if (preg_match('/\AVS-order-export-\d+\.xml\z/', $file)) {`

Comment: Ah! that's working now. Thanks for your help @The fourth bird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pattern you are trying to match a comma followed by a space which are not present.

For a more specific pattern, you could use

```
\AVS-order-export-\d+\.xml\z
```

- `\A` Start of string
- `VS-order-export-` Match literally
- `\d+\.xml` Match 1+ digits and `.xml`
- `\z` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/74VsJ5/1)

For example

```
if (preg_match('/\AVS-order-export-\d+\.xml\z/', $file)) {
```